# changing the color of a <div> when clicked

Tags: javascript

Thanks ALOT guys! I've got it working now, thank you!

I have a hopefully easy question: 
This: http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/
is what I want to achieve, but I can't seem to get it working.
I'm all new to javascript, so I'm not sure how to properly put the script in the html document.
I have tried the `<script type="text/javascript">` and others, but it just doesn't work.

So i wondered if anyone would take the time to put it in a html document and get it working, and ofcourse posting the entire code. I would be very greatfull!

my doc:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px;
  margin:5px;  
    display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
    $(this)
        .css('background-color','#00ff66')
        .siblings()
        .css('background-color','#ffffff');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
    Group 2
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  It'd be a lot easier just to point out what's wrong with that (not to mention a good learning experience)

Comment: Sounds like you were looking for this: [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

Comment: I would guess your issue is you have not included the jquery library above the script.  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" />

Comment: [jqFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Put this somewhere in your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.childDiv').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
            $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
        });
   });
</script>
```

You can put it more or less anywhere, but just before the `</body>` tag would be a good place.

And as @MarkK has rightly pointed out, you need to reference the jQuery library itself.

This goes between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jsfiddle, you can right-click on the Results pane and View Source.  This will give you the exact html that produces the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
  margin:5px;  
    display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});



});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
    Group 2
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that, but must have missed it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import jQuery (the library that contains the `$` functions).  This is simple, just add

```
<script src="http.//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your HTML, before your other script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!--inclue jquery - change the path 'src'. the default is jquery.js is on the same location of this html-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <sript type="text/javascript">
       jQuery().ready(function($){

          $('.childDiv').click(function(){
             $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color','#ffffff');
             $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
           });

       });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!--the content paste your html here-->
   </body>
</html>
```